# optionsTextバインディングなどでシングルクォーテーションが必要なのはなぜ？

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Knockout.jsの`optionsText`バインディングや`optionsValue`バインディングでは、プロパティの名前をシングルクォーテーションで囲う必要があるのは、なぜでしょうか。

```html
<select data-bind="value: selectedValue,
                   options: list,
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   optionsValue: 'value'"></select>
```

どのオプションにシングルクォーテーションが必要なのか覚えるのが大変なので、そもそも「なぜシングルクォーテーションが必要なのか」その原理を理解したいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`optionsText`バインディングは「オプションのプロパティ名」または「オプションを引数に取り、文字列を返す関数」が許可されています。もし前者の値で引用符の省略を許可した場合、後者に親ビューモデルの関数を指定する場合と区別しにくいからではないでしょうか。